# Unity ads not initilizing automatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads, unity-editor

I am using unity reward based Ads in my android/iOS game. but when I check it   `Advertisement.IsReady (rewardVideoID);`

always return false.

Also if check in Awake unity ads initialization is false

```
void Awake ()
{
    Debug.Log ("Unity ads ini state : " + Advertisement.isInitialized); //it is false everytime
}
```

But I have enabled ads in Unity Editor so here I want to know why unity ads are not auto initializing. I used unity ads in my previous project it is initializing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `Advertisement.Initialize` before checking `Advertisement.isInitialized` or `Advertisement.IsReady`.

Not just that. When you call `Advertisement.Initialize`, there is no guarantee that it will initialize immediately. This is why you must perform this check in a coroutine function so that you can continuously check it until it has initialized.

An example from [Unity's Ads Doc](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/monetization/integration-guide-unity):

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
!UNITY_ADS // If the Ads service is not enabled...
    if (Advertisement.isSupported)
    { // If runtime platform is supported...
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, enableTestMode); // ...initialize.
    }
if

    // Wait until Unity Ads is initialized,
    //  and the default ad placement is ready.
    while (!Advertisement.isInitialized || !Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }

    // Show the default ad placement.
    Advertisement.Show();
}
```

Comment: but according to unity latest versions of unity does not require manually initialization

Comment: You don't if you are using UnityAds with automatic initialization enabled in the Editor. The purpose of my answer is to tell you that `Advertisement.isInitialized` and  `Advertisement.IsReady` are not bound to be true immediately. You have to check them constantly in the `Update` function or use coroutine and a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Select either Android or iOS as active build target. Unity Ads doesn't support standalone.
Its in File -> Build Settings -> Platform